# Add pushpin to image

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I created a line map and save it as jpeg, I would like to use it for my windows application in c#.

What I wanted to do is click on the specific area of image and and add a pushpin on it and add some information, so that I can click on it later to reveal the information on it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to get a specific area inside your picturebox when mouse is clicked. You can do it with this:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int xCoordinate = e.X;
        int yCoordinate = e.Y;

        var picture = new PictureBox
        {
            Size = new Size(50, 50),
            Location = new Point(e.X, e.Y),
            Image = Image.FromFile("pushpin.png"),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

        };
        this.Controls.Add(picture);
        picture.BringToFront();
    }
```

**UPDATE:** I've also added how you should add the image.

This should be the result:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Should I use picturebox or something here?...  there's no such tap event in picturebox...

Comment: Oh, apologies. Should've asked what platform are you developing.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Windows Forms, because you're using picturebox. Am I right?

Comment: Yes! and thank you so much, but I think, there is a little issue? When the form is in maximized the coordinate become different...

Comment: How did you set up your picture box? Is it resizing whenever you resize the form?